# Looking for more "exotic" classes of polyhedra

Tags: geometry, soft-question, big-list, polyhedra

I am aware of the Platonic Solids, the Archimedean Solids, the Catalan Solids, the Johnson solids, Goldberg polyhedra, deltahedra and some zonohedra.

I am interested in more names of polyhedra, specifically 3D polyhedra with iscosehedral symmetry and unit edge lengths. I do not require regular faces (as something like the rectified truncated icosahedron and the snub rhombic triacontahedron are the sort of polyhedra I am interested in). I am also interested in links to images.

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as the quality is good. The question can be answered precisely. It is also something of significant personal interest to me. It seems a shame that this site would push out a question like this.

Comment: The wikipedia page for polyhedra does not seem complete either. Where else do I ask such a question?

Comment: It took me a long time to find these examples of rhombic polyhedra with icosahedral symmetry and I want more: http://www.orchidpalms.com/polyhedra/rhombic/icosarhom.htm

Comment: Are you acquainted with [permutahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron)?

Comment: No, I'm not. I think I need to clarify my question. I want 3D polyhedra, with icosahedral symmetry and I think unit edge lengths.

Comment: I see you've already mentioned the Johnson solids, but I just want to emphasize that the last nine are crazy

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unit edge lengths." I thought you meant equilateral polyhedra, but that doesn't seem to be true of the rectified truncated icosahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend these:

- [Dual Geodesic Icosahedra](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedra.html)
- [polyHédronisme](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10wC)

Comment: Wonderful! This is the sort of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Did you check this address? I think you can get good information there.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron

Comment: Thanks. Stellated polyhedra are less interesting to me and the Archimedean Solids already make up a large proportion of vertex transitive polyhedra, so I am familiar with most of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are some among the [symmetrohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrohedron). In particular, I know that the one below can be realized with unique edge length, and probably others from that family can too.

[image]

The depicted one has Conway notation $\mathrm{dL_0dI}$